# Problema con menú css en Safari

Tags: css, safari

estoy teniendo este problema con safari.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esa es mi app

Cuando le doy al boton del menú en cualquier navegador me sale esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando lo hago en safari sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a deshabilitar la imagen y así si me funciona. Incluso quitándole a la imagen el fixed tambien. Pero con z-index no me va..

Aqui dejo el codigo:

//Menú que se abre al pulsar

```
.menu-default #navbar .navbar-collapse {
    height: auto;
    min-height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    left: 0;
    top:0;
}
```

//Imagen de fondo:

```
.image-edit{
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo? Me vendría bien una ayudita

Comment: en que navegadores funciona?, puedes agregar una captura de del inspector web de safari para verifar si existe un desvordamiento.

Comment: Revise el web sin embargo no tengo un Mac para verificar que esta pasando.